# List remote (PE) IAT Functions

Tags: c++, import, portable-executable

I am trying to list all the imported functions from a certain DLL in another process (through the PE header),

```
if (!_stricmp(pName, pDLLname)){

            // get the import list table

            pILT = new IMAGE_THUNK_DATA[dwThunkArrayLen];
            bSuccess = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                (LPCVOID)((DWORD)lpImageBaseAddress +
                idescriptor.OriginalFirstThunk),
                pILT,
                BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

            // get the import address table

            pIAT = new IMAGE_THUNK_DATA[dwThunkArrayLen];
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                (LPCVOID)((DWORD)lpImageBaseAddress +
                idescriptor.FirstThunk),
                pIAT,
                BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

            if (!pIAT)
                printf("Error reading Address Table\n");

   /* This is where I'm having trouble, it doesn't output correct function names*/

            while (pIAT->u1.Function){
                PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME pimport = new IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME;
                bSuccess = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                    (LPCVOID)((DWORD)lpImageBaseAddress +
                    pIAT->u1.AddressOfData),
                    pimport,
                    BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

                printf("%s\n", pimport->Name);
                pIAT++;
        }
} /* If matched DLL */
```

I can successfully list the DLL's but not the functions.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A lot of things wrong here.  Definitely starting with BUFFER_SIZE, you'll need to match the actual data size.

Comment: After loading, the IAT points to functions, not their names

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the image help API? Why do you feel compelled to do this with ReadProcessMemory?

Comment: @Harold so what contains the names? the ILT?

Comment: The INT, I'm not sure what you mean by ILT

Comment: @Harold Yeah I think we are talking about the same thing